# Unable to store value from dictionary in variable

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a configuration file in JSON format. This file is converted into a Python (3.8) Dict named `config`, which is a global variable. When I try to get the value from any of the keys and attempt to store them in a a variable called `test` I get the following error: `'NameError: name 'apiResponseOrder' is not defined'`

I verified that the config variable is in fact a dict. (type check returns `<class 'dict'>`)

I am able to loop through the dict and print all the key-value pairs.
The for loop prints values for the following keys: `inputDir`, `outputDir`, `apiResponseOrder`

```
def processHiscoreItem():
    print(type(config))

    for key, value in config.items():
        print(key)
        print(value)

    test = config.get(apiResponseOrder)
    print(test)
```

What is going wrong here? Why can I print the values of the keys, but cannot store them in the test variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test = config.get(apiResponseOrder)` --> `test = config.get('apiResponseOrder')`

Answer (score 0):

apiResponseOrder is probably of str type, so you need to do this, instead

```
    test = config.get('apiResponseOrder')
```